# Custom post type issue

Tags: custom-post-types

I have been trying to create my first custom post type. But I does'nt seem to succeed since nothing is showing up in my admin menu at all. I have looked over my code 100 times but I can't figure out whats wrong..

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'properties_post_type' );

function properties_post_type() {

    $args = array(

        'description'         => __( 'Post type to manage properties', ' ' ), // string
        'public'              => true, // bool (default is FALSE)
        'publicly_queryable'  => true, // bool (defaults to 'public').
        'exclude_from_search' => false, // bool (defaults to 'public')
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false, // bool (defaults to 'public')
        'show_ui'             => true, // bool (defaults to 'public')
        'show_in_menu'        => true, // bool (defaults to 'show_ui')
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true, // bool (defaults to 'show_in_menu')
        'menu_position'       => 6, // int (defaults to 25 - below comments)
        'menu_icon'           => null, // string (defaults to use the post icon)
        'can_export'          => true, // bool (defaults to TRUE)
        'delete_with_user'    => true, // bool (defaults to TRUE if the post type supports 'author')
        'hierarchical'        => false, // bool (defaults to FALSE)
        'has_archive'         => 'false', // bool|string (defaults to FALSE)
        'query_var'           => 'properties', // bool|string (defaults to TRUE - post type name)
        'capability_type'     => 'post', // string|array (defaults to 'post')
        'map_meta_cap'        => true, // bool (defaults to FALSE)

        'rewrite' => array(

            'slug'       => 'property', // string (defaults to the post type name)
            'with_front' => false, // bool (defaults to TRUE)
            'pages'      => true, // bool (defaults to TRUE)
            'feeds'      => true, // bool (defaults to the 'has_archive' argument)
            'ep_mask'    => EP_PERMALINK, // const (defaults to EP_PERMALINK)
        ),


        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'author',
            'thumbnail',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes',
            'post-formats',
        ),

        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => __( 'Properties',                   ' ' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'Property',                    ' ' ),
            'menu_name'          => __( 'Properties',                   ' ' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => __( 'Properties',                   ' ' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New',                    ' ' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Property',            ' ' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Property',               ' ' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Property',                ' ' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Property',               ' ' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Properties',            ' ' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No properties found',          ' ' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No properties found in trash', ' ' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All properties',               ' ' ),
            'archive_title'      => __( 'Properties',                   ' ' ),
        )
    );

    /* Register the post type. */
    register_post_type(
        'properties', 
        $args      // Arguments for post type.
    );
}

?>
<!-- END CUSTOM POST TYPES -->
```

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to succeed"? :) What do you expect to happen that doesn't? There are a lot of ways to configure CPTs in regards to interface from very obvious to very subtle.

Comment: I have updated the post now  :) My issue is that nothing shows up in my dashboard. I dont get a new meny or a editor :)

Comment: Putting your code as-is into my dev install work just fine and makes Properties appear in admin menu under Posts.

Comment: Thats wierd.. It does'nt work for me..

Comment: Check if the file is actually getting loaded and stuff.

Comment: Code sounds good (tried here also and works) only thing (what I/the most would miss) it has no options for tags and categories `'taxonomies' => array( 'category','post_tag'),`.

Comment: Did you resave your permalinks settings?

Comment: On which file, you code? function.php?
Coz custom post types are functional aspect of Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help! I Re-wrote the whole code and then it was working. I have no idea why it was'nt working the first time!